# Mongoid 5.0 - Rails 4 - Finder stop working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, console, mongoid

Any idea what happened?

I'm just trying to find the first object like

```
User.first
```

and the returning is always a random object, and then I try

```
User.last
```

the result is the same object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using mongoid 5.0, the first and last do not work without explicitly defining the sort

From the [changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> ## 3768 first and last no longer add an _id sort when no sorting options have been provided. In order to guarantee that a document is the first or last, it needs to now contain an explicit sort.

This will work

```
User.asc(:id).first
```